# Multiple FilterLists in HBase

Tags: hbase, nosql

Is it possible to have multiple FilterLists while performing a scan in HBase ? If yes, how ? By multiple FilterLists I do not mean multiple Filters.

Comment: The reason i want it is because in a filterlist you can do either AND operation or OR operation on all the filters. What if i want to use both the operations ??

Comment: Good point, I hadn't realized that would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `FilterList` is itself a `Filter`, you can build a `FilterList` that contains other `FilterList` instances. To quote the docs:

> Since you can use Filter Lists as children of Filter Lists, you can
>   create a hierarchy of filters to be evaluated.

This allows combining `FilterList` instances for complex and/or logic:

```
FilterList combineFilterLists(FilterList list1, FilterList list2) {
  return new FilterList(list1, list2)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I read that but if you look closely there is no method or constructor in `FilterList` which would allow you to do so.

Comment: @articuno Every single one of the constructors will allow you to do so. To reiterate, a `FilterList`, *is* a `Filter`.

Comment: I can create two separate filters with different operation but I cannot use both of them in a single `Scan`

Comment: Yes, you can, that is what `FilterList` is for. See my new edit for an example.

Comment: I did not find any such constructor which takes `FilterList` type as input argument in HBase documentation. Though I'll try what you suggested. Thanks :)